# Filter in MDX query with Date Range filter and Year Filter

Tags: sql, mdx, olap, olap-cube, mondrian

I'm trying to filter my MDX query of can someone help me on how this can be done.
My code

```
Select
[Measures].[Net_Cost] on 0,
[State].[City] on 1

FROM 
[SALES]

WHERE
([Date].[Date.AYearly].[2017]),([Date].[Date.AMonthly].[1] : [Date].[Date.AMonthly].[12])
```

and it throws an error.

I want to accomplish the following:

Where
year = 2017 and month is between 1 and current month.

How can this be done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try one filter in a subselect and the other in the outer query:

```
SELECT
   [Measures].[Net_Cost] on 0,
   [State].[City] on 1
FROM 
  (
   SELECT 
     [Date].[Date.AYearly].[2017] ON 0
   FROM [SALES]
  )
WHERE
([Date].[Date.AMonthly].[1] : [Date].[Date.AMonthly].[12])
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @whythe1 i did something like this

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY
 [Date].[Date.AYearly].[Year].[2017]:
 [Date].[Date.AYearly].[Year].[2017].PrevMember ON 0,

NON EMPTY
CROSSJOIN
(
    CROSSJOIN(
    {[Measures].[Net_Prod_Cost]},
    {[Territory].[Sales_Territory_Branch_Number].Members,
    [Territory].[Sales_Territory_Branch].Members}
    ),
    {[Products].[Products.SBM].[RYAN WEST]}
 ) ON ROWS

FROM [SALES]

WHERE
(
({[Date].[Date.AMonthly].[Month].[1] : 
     [Date].[Date.AMonthly].[Month].[11]})
)}
```

and it worked.

Thanks your answer gave me an idea.